# javascript array join() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

someone can help me to understand this script:

```
String.prototype.padLeft = function(width, char) {

    var result = this;
    char = char || " ";

    if (this.length < width)  {
        result = new Array(width - this.length + 1).join(char) + this;
    }
    return result;
};
console.log("abc".padLeft(10,"-"));
```

So.. im extend the object String with a new method.
The char parameter is optional (if omitted, the function will use white space)
I dont have clear this part:

```
result = new Array(width - this.length + 1).join(char) + this;
```

Am i creating a new array with 8 element that are undefined and then separate them with the separetor? Is it correct? Why there is a"+1" in the array definition? Thank you in advance

Comment: array is used mostly for the join function. It is concatenated immediately.

Comment: interested code, generate a char at begin of string

Comment: the `+1` is needed because joining an array of length = n, results in n-1 separators. Ex: `['a','b','c'].join('-')` results in "a-b-c". But this algorithm wants n separators, so the `+1`.

Answer (score 1):

### `new Array(width - this.length + 1).join(char)`

This ^ is effectively saying "make an empty array with `n` number of slots, then join the empty slots together using the `char` to separate each empty slot. So, if `char = "0"`, and `n = 3`, we get `000`.

**`width - this.length + 1`** is used to determine the number of characters needed to be added to beginning of the string.

Then we add that to the beginning of the original string: `this`

### `+1`

You need the + 1 because of how join works.

```
new Array(1).join('0') = ""      // wrong
new Array(1+1).join('0') = "0"   // correct
new Array(2).join('0') = "0"     // wrong
new Array(2+1).join('0') = "00"  // correct
```

Comment: The `+1` is incorrect though, right? In his example it would be `10 - 3 + 1 = 8` which would make the whole string `3 + 8 = 11`.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

When you join an array with `N` elements, there will be `N-1` separators between the elements. The code is using `join` to create a string with just `N` separators, so you need to give it an array with `N+1` elements to account for this.